# How to do a get request from Node to an API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to a get request to an API.

This is what I have in Angular

Service:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .factory('Search', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/show/:search');
  });
```

Ctrl:

```
$scope.$watch('searchStr', function (tmpStr)
{
  if (!tmpStr || tmpStr.length == 0)
    return 0;


    // if searchStr is still the same..
    // go ahead and retrieve the data
    if (tmpStr === $scope.searchStr) {   
      console.log(Search);       
      Search.get({string: $scope.searchStr})
      .$promise.then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.responseData = data;
      })
    }

});
```

View:

```
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="searchStr">

    <textarea> {{responseData}} </textarea>
```

Nodejs so far:

```
app.get('api/show/:search', function(req, res, next) { 
    request.get('http://thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=' + search, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('error', error);
      console.log('response', response);
      console.log('BODY', body);
    });
});
```

what I need is to get a response from that link above when the user is searching, but all I get is the response from the first get to `api/show/:search`, what am I missing?

Comment: i don't understand this "what I need is to get a response from that link above when the user is searching, but all I get is the response from the first get to api/show/:search" can you explain more ?

Comment: @MayK what I need is a query of results coming from here "'http://thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname='"

Answer (score 0):

replace search with req.params.search

```
app.get('api/show/:search', function(req, res, next) { 
    request.get('http://thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=' + req.params.search, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(error, response, body);
    });
});
```